# Displaying the image which paste in rich text box to Crystal report in C# with Access Database

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am developing question paper generator for student in windows application     with c# language in visual . right now stuck on this problem  , i have a rich Text box in the form where we can paste maths quadratic equations from Ms word or word pad .  now i wants that pasted quadratic equation must save in database and must display in crystal report .(saving is properly working with ole object but cant able to show in crystal report) I go through many website and forums and many other options like changing datatypes of db with memo , with text interpreation to RTF text and ole object and saving equations in byte form but haven't get the answer yet , there is nothing shown in crystal report from rich text box i tried with blob also but not seen any  .  here is my Database in access :  ID = Number , Question = Text , Equations = OLE object  ( quadratic equation saving from rich text box) Thank you ,  Hope will get the answer soon.

```
code for saving in database
 byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtf);
                try{
                    OleDbConnection oldb = new OleDbConnection("connection string");

                    oldb.Open();
                    string query = "insert into table_temp(question , objects , object2) values( @questions , @obj  , @obj2)";
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oldb);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questions", richTextBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@obj", bytes);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@obj2", richTextBox2.Rtf);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("save", "save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

// code for displaying in report . 


                 DataSet ds_temp = new DataSet();
                 string query_temp = "select * from table_temp "; 
                 OleDbCommand cmd_temp = new OleDbCommand(query_temp, oldb);
                 cmd_temp.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 OleDbDataAdapter adp_temp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd_temp);
                 adp_temp.Fill(ds_temp);
                 mathematical_formulla.temp_report obj = new mathematical_formulla.temp_report();
                 ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
                 reportform rpt = new reportform();
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                 dt = ds_temp.Tables[0];
                 obj.SetDataSource(dt);
                 rpt.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = obj;
                 rpt.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks !! Now i got the answer , and also wants to share this .

First of all take the rich text box and connect them with word pad

```
richTextBox2.SelectedRtf = Properties.Resources.Document;
```

write the Maths equation and reflect back to RTB than take a screen shot of RTB in picture box by following code .

```
 public static Bitmap RtbToBitmap(RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            rtb.Update(); // Ensure RTB fully painted
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rtb.Width, rtb.Height);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                gr.CopyFromScreen(rtb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, rtb.Size);
            }
            return bmp;
        }
```

now the picture box having an image and convert this image into byte array and store in DB and this equation will reflect into Crystal report also .

thanks you .